# Difference between a Metaphor and a Simile

Tags: metaphors, simile

I know a metaphor compares two similar things, like a ballerina glides like a swan and that a simile compares two unlike things, but I'm still not sure if the sentence, "The car guzzles fuel." would be a simile or a metaphor?  Could someone clarify it for me? Thanks.

Comment: The simile is a formulaic metaphor, a sub-type. The distinction often made in school teaching is not recognised by linguists.

Answer (score 3):

"The car guzzles fuel" is a personification, which is a type of metaphor. The words "like" and "as" circumvent the hyperbole or unreality inherent to metaphors. "The car burns fuel like David guzzles beer."

Edit: to be clear, the words "like" and "as" are the most common markers of similes.